# How do I target a single input focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I target a single `input focus`.

```
    $(".right input").focus(function(){
    $(".left span").addClass('focus');
}).blur(function(){
    $(".left span").removeClass('focus');
});
```

This code adds the class to all of the `span` elements when I focus on an `input`
How would I set it so it can only add the class to the `input` that is being focused?
Here is my html

```
<div class="left">
  <span class="name"></span>
  <span class="email"></span>
  <span class="phone"></span>
  <span class="address"></span>
</div>
<div class="right">
<p>
<label for="name">Your Name:</label>
<input id="name" type="text" value="Name" autocomplete="off">
</p>
<p>
<label for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input id="email" type="text" value="Email" autocomplete="off">
</p>
<p>
<label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
<input id="phone" type="text" value="Phone" autocomplete="off">
</p>
<p>
<label for="address">Your Address:</label>
<input id="address" type="text" value="Address Line 1" autocomplete="off">
</p>
<p>
<label for="address2">Line Address 2:(optional)</label>
<input id="address2" type="text" value="Address Line 2" autocomplete="off">
</p>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Could I implement the code given in the answer selected to this code?

```
        // Trying to target font customization on single input focus
    // and not all together
    $("#fs").change(function() { // change font family style.
        $('.email').css("font-family", $(this).val());
    });
    $("#size").change(function() { // change font size.
        $('.email').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "pt");
    });
```

To edit the `span` belonging to the `input` that is focused on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this` reference

```
 $(".right input").focus(function(){
    $(".left").find('.'+this.id).addClass('focus');  //<--find element with those classes inside .left element
 }).blur(function(){
   $(".left").find('.'+this.id).removeClass('focus');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.right input').each(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  $(this).bind('focus', function(){
     $('.left').find('.'+ id).addClass('focus');
  });

  $(this).bind('blur', function(){
    $('.left').find('.'+ id).removeClass('focus');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/PXX5W/)**

```
 $(".right input").focus(function(){
     var cls = $(this).prop('id');
     $(".left span."+cls).addClass('focus');
 }).blur(function(){
     $(".left span").removeClass('focus');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(".right input").focus(function(){
    $(".left span."+this.id).addClass('focus');
}).blur(function(){
    $(".left span."+this.id).removeClass('focus');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/Uug8L/1/)**